# Mongoose models' save() won't update empty array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, model, save

I have an array (`bookedby`) in a Mongoose model defined like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var BarSchema = new Schema({
      date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      barid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      bookedby: {
        type: [String],
        required: true
      },
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Bar', BarSchema);
```

I update it with following function, called by a nodejs express router:

```
const Bars = require("../../models/bars");
const { getToday } = require('../../utils');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
  const { barid } = req.body;
  const { username } = req.user;
  const date = getToday();

  if( !barid ) return res.json({ success: false, error: 'Please specify parameter \'barid\'.'})

  Bars.findOne({ barid, date }, function (err, bar) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    if (!bar || bar.bookedby.indexOf(username) === -1) return res.json({ error: `Bar is not booked yet.` });

    // Someone booked the bar
    const index = bar.bookedby.indexOf(username);
    bar.bookedby.splice(index, 1);
    bar.save(err => {
      if (err) res.json({ error: `Error saving booking.` });
      else res.json({ success: true });
    });
  });
};
```

Everything works fine, except when I remove the last item from the `bookedby` array. Then the save() function doesn't update the database. The last item remains there. I guess it has something to do with mongodb optimizing empty arrays, but how  can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mongoose FAQ:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html

For version >= 3.2.0 you should use the array.set() syntax:

```
doc.array.set(3, 'changed');
doc.save();
```

If you are running a version less than 3.2.0, you must mark the array modified before saving:

```
doc.array[3] = 'changed';
doc.markModified('array');
doc.save();
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work for me. I found another way to do it: Bars.findOneAndUpdate({ barid, date }, { $pull: { bookedby: username } }). And adding ist just $push instead of $pull. Work like charm. I'm starting to like MongoDB.